# "ORA-00984: column not allowed here" while executing clob insert in .net

Tags: .net, plsql, clob

Getting the error "ORA-00984: column not allowed here" while inserting data in the CLOBTable.HEM_RICS column is of the type clob .

```
Public Function Insertdata(ByVal pid As Integer, ByVal pdatefromDate As    DateTime, ByVal pdatetoDate As DateTime, ByVal parray As String()) As Boolean
        Try
             Dim lst As String = "Admin"
            Dim lstrSQL As String = "INSERT INTO CLOBTABLE (HEM_EXCH_ID,HEM_FROM_DATE,HEM_TO_DATE,HEM_RICS,HEM_CREATED_BY,HEM_CREATED_DATE) VALUES (pintexchId,pdatefromDate,pdatetoDate,:parrRICS,lst,pdatetoDate) "
            ldbParameter = New OracleParameter
            ldbParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            ldbParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob
            ldbParameter.ParameterName = "parrRICS"
            ldbParameter.Value = parrRICS.ToString()

            lcmdCommand = Nothing
            lcmdCommand = gobjclsDBManager.Provider.CreateCommand()
            lcmdCommand.Connection = gobjclsDBManager.DBConnection 'Contains the connection string
            lcmdCommand.Parameters.Add(ldbParameter)
            lcmdCommand.CommandText = lstrSQL
            If lcmdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
```

Comment: IN your values clause you need values not columns.

Comment: it has values.the values are passed from a different function